# Selenium Python - element click intercepted

Tags: selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to click `select a service` - `Single knowledge test` on the following page:
https://onlinebusiness.icbc.com/qmaticwebbooking/#/

I think I located the button target as follows:
`<input aria-checked="true" id="da8488da9b5df26d32ca58c6d6a7973bedd5d98ad052d62b468d3b04b080ea25" role="radio" type="radio" name="v-radio-50" value="da8488da9b5df26d32ca58c6d6a7973bedd5d98ad052d62b468d3b04b080ea25">`

But when I try to click it with the following code:
`driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[type='radio'][value='da8488da9b5df26d32ca58c6d6a7973bedd5d98ad052d62b468d3b04b080ea25']").click()`

I get the following error:
**ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element `<input aria-checked="false" id="da8488da9b5df26d32ca58c6d6a7973bedd5d98ad052d62b468d3b04b080ea25" role="radio" type="radio" name="v-radio-50" value="da8488da9b5df26d32ca58c6d6a7973bedd5d98ad052d62b468d3b04b080ea25">` is not clickable at point (219, 479). Other element would receive the click: `<div class="v-input--selection-controls__ripple"></div>`
(Session info: chrome=84.0.4147.105)**.

It persists even after running
`driver.find_element_by_class_name('v-input--selection-controls__ripple').click()` first.

I know there are lots of similar questions around, but as a newbie to Selenium I didn't found a solution that could solve the problem for me. I've been stuck on it for quite a while, so many thanks for anyone who could kindly help!

Comment: The page is returning HTTP ERROR 403.

Comment: @bertdida. I just noticed this as well.. Hopefully it could recover soon.  I'll archive the question until the page works again. Thanks.

Comment: @bertdida. I think the page is back now.